# In JavaScript, how to replace every $WORD with an href to website while keeping the original message unchanged?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a bit stumped. I am working with StockTwits data and one of the requirements of their API is that you need to link their 'cashtags' (a hashtag but instead of using # they use $).

My input data is

> This is my amazing message with a stock $symbol that I need to click on

and what I need back (in string format) is

> This is my amazing message with a stock `<a href ='https://stocktwits.com/symbol' target='_blank> $symbol </a>` that I need to click on

Obviously when it gets rendered I would just have `$symbol` clickable instead of the entire a href tag.

If it helps, for each message I have an array of all the symbols that will appear (without a $) infront of them.

Right now I am trying to do this and it is a bit messy but not sure how to get it to work right. I am doing this in react.

```
//Message incoming is: 'This is my amazing message with a stock $symbol that I need to click on'
const message_body = unescape(this.props.data.body)

//used for finding what words to replace. Output is ['symbol1', 'symbol2', 'symbol3']
let find = [];
for(let symbl of this.props.data.symbols){
  find.push(symbl.symbol)

}

//used for setting the values I want to replace in the incoming message 
let replace = [];
for(let symbl of find){
  let url = `https://stocktwits.com/${symbl}`
  let link = `<a href=${url} target="_blank">${symbl}</a>`
  replace.push(link)

}

//using the replace-once library, it takes the message, words to find, what to replace them with, and global or not.
let formed_message = replaceOnce(message_body, find, replace, 'gi')

...... 

//using react-html-parser to convert the <a href> tags into a clickable link
<Card.Text>{ReactHtmlParser(formed_message)}</Card.Text>
```

What all my code will output is

> This is my amazing message with a stock $symbol that I need to click on

but the `$` is not included in the link, as well as if `symbol` appears anywhere else, it will make it a link. Example below

> $GOOG $SPY $AAPL off topic. Good job GOOGle!

in the above message, it still turns `GOOGL`e into a link, and I only want the ones leading with a $ to be considered.

Like I said, this is super messy and I am close but open to any and all suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: look into escaping special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
let formed_message = this.props.data.symbols.map({symbol} = symbol).reduce(
      (p, s) => p.replace(`$${s}`, `<a href ='https://stocktwits.com/${s}' target='_blank> $${s}</a>`), 
      message_body
)
```

```js
const message_body = "This is my amazing message with a stock $symbol that I need to click on and also test $symbol2";

console.log(['symbol', 'symbol2', 'symbol3'].reduce(
      (p, s) => p.replace(`$${s}`, `<a href ='https://stocktwits.com/${s}' target='_blank> $${s}</a>`), 
      message_body
))
```

Comment: so this works when I am doing the console log, but nothing comes back when I try to assign it to the variable like you have in your first code snippet

edit: for some reason ReactHtmlParser no longer likes it. But other then that, this looks to be exaclty what I was hoping for!

Comment: @Brian please try again, i've edited the first snipped

Comment: again it works, but now the issue i am Having is that ReactHtmlParser doesn't seem to like the tags anymore. The issue i found is that I need to wrap the entire thing in a tag in order to work. gives me the error  ```<p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match all words preceded by a dollar symbol.

```js
let text = 'This is my amazing message with a stock $symbol that I need to click on';
let res = text.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, (match,group)=>
   `<a href ='https://stocktwits.com/${group}' target='_blank> ${match} </a>`);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: but this won't work if there are words that have `$` that are not in the symbols list, no?

Comment: this also works, thank you! now i just need HTML parser to not yell at me and say
 ```<p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>```